Can one define second-order equinumerosity in MSO via first-order cardinality quantifiers?
Let $L$ be MSO (Monadic Second Order Logic) extended with an $n$-ary second-order cardinality predicate (i.e., a first-order cardinality quantifier) $C_R$ for every $n$-ary relation $R$ on the naturals and two additional unary second-order predicates $F$ and $G$. Say that a model $M$ is admissible provided that it is finite and interprets $C_R$ as follows: $(A_1,...,A_n) \in C_R^M$ iff $(|A_1|,...,|A_n|) \in R$ for sets $A_1,...,A_n$ of elements of $M$.
The cardinality predicates $C_R$ let one define arbitrarily complicated counting of elements of sets, allowing one to express things like "$|X|+3^{|Y|}=\operatorname{BusyBeaver}(|Z|)$" for monadic second-order variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$. I am wondering if this is enough to let one define "The number of sets $X$ such that $\phi(X)$ is equal to the number of sets $Y$ such that $\psi(Y)$". In other words, can we go from counting elements to counting sets, or more precisely:
Question: Is there a sentence of $\phi$ of $L$ such that $M\vDash \phi$ iff $|F^M|=|G^M|$ for all admissible models $M$?
I conjecture that the answer is negative, but can't prove it. I also suspect that the question is still negative if all we want to do is define the parity of $|F^M|$.
FO rephrasing: Say that an admissible model $M=({\cal P}A,\sigma,I)$ has the powerset of a finite set $A$ as its objects, a signature $\sigma$ consisting of $\subseteq$, unary predicates $F$ and $G$, and an $n$-ary predicate $C_R$ for every $n$-ary relation on the naturals, and an interpretation $I$ such that $\subseteq^I$ is the standard subset relation and $C_R^I = \{ (a_1,...,a_n) \in ({\cal P}A)^n : (|a_1|,...,|a_n|)\in R \}$. Then the question is whether there is a sentence $\phi$ of $\sigma$ such that $M\vDash \phi$ iff $|F^I|=|G^I|$ for every admissible $M=({\cal P}A,\sigma,I)$.
Note: If the only predicate $C_R$ we had was equinumerosity (i.e., $R$ had to be identity on the naturals), I think the answer would be negative since van Benthem and Icard recently showed that in MSO with equinumerosity the only relations one could define between cardinalities are semi-linear, while the possibility of defining $|F^M|=|G^M|$ would allow one to define power-of-two relations.

What exactly can $L$ quantify over? You say $L$ is second-order, but then expressing $\vert F\vert=\vert G\vert$ is trivial. Separately, why doesn't the sentence $$C_{=}(F,G)$$ do the job?

1st-order variables (written with lower-case letters) range over "objects" and 2nd-order variables (upper-case letters) range over sets of objects. 2nd-order predicates take 2nd-order variables as arguments. Since, $C_=$ is a 2nd-order predicate, it takes 2nd-order variables: $C_=(X,Y)$. But $F$ and $G$ are 2nd-order predicates ($F(X)$ and $G(X)$ only make sense for $X$ a 2nd-order variable), and would only be possible values for a 3rd-order variable, but the logic here is 2nd-order, so there are no 3rd-order variables. So $C_=(F,G)$ is not in $L$.

I’m not sure whether I translated it correctly from descriptive complexity to computational complexity, but since you allow arbitrary numerical predicates, doesn’t your question amount to asking whether $\mathrm{C_=P}$ (no direct relation to your $C_=$ notation) is included in PH/poly (which is actually equivalent to: is PH = CH)? Then it’s almost certainly false, but you won’t be able to prove that with current technology.

@Emil Jeřábek: Is there a chance you could try to do the translation rigorously and write it up as an answer? I know very little about computational complexity, and my own thinking was that there is no obvious computational complexity reduction implied by an affirmative answer. (To naively check if $F$ and $G$ have equal numbers of satisfiers is to go through all $2^{|A|}$ subsets of $A$. If there is a $\phi$ as in the question, then instead we have to check if $\phi$ is true, but naively that also requires going through all $2^{|A|}$ subsets of $A$ for each universal quantifier.)

One approach might be to look at graphs and compare the expressive power of MSO$_1$+all cardinality predicates vs. MSO$_2$+all cardinality predicates. But I don't know much about graphs.

On second thought, since the interpretations of $F$ and $G$ can be arbitrary, this really means $\mathrm{C_=P}^A\subseteq\mathrm{PH}^A/\mathrm{poly}$ for all oracles $A$ (whence $\mathrm{CH}^A=\mathrm{PH}^A$). This is actually known to be false, as there are oracles $A$ such that the polynomial hierarchy does not colapse.

I could try to write something later if I find the time. But frankly, I don’t see the point: if you “know very little about complexity theory”, to the extent that you are even oblivious of the basic correspondence of SO to PH, you will not understand the answer anyway. The expressive power of fragments of second- and higher-order logic on finite structures is complexity theory in thin disguise, and you won’t get anywhere with the subject unless you learn some complexity theory.

@Emil Jeřábek: My bad: I did mean monadic second-order.

The answer is negative even for nonmonadic second-order logic by complexity considerations.
Assume for contradiction that such a sentence $\phi$ exists.
First, let us see how difficult it is to check that a given finite structure satisfies $\phi$. It is a standard fact that if $\phi$ were just an ordinary SO sentence (with only first-order relations and functions), then checking its truth in a structure $\mathcal M=([n],\dots)$ presented by the tables of the relations and functions can be done in the polynomial hierarchy PH, i.e., in $\Sigma^P_k$ for some constant $k$; in particular, an existential SO quantifier can be evaluated by nondeterministically guessing a witness (which takes $n^{O(1)}$ bits to write down), and dually for universal quantifiers.
Here we have to be more careful because we have more complex atomic formulas:

$C_R$: Counting the number of elements in a set can be done in polynomial time, but checking whether $(n_1,\dots,n_k)\in R$ may not be even computable for arbitrary $R$. However, the finitely many $R$’s that occur in $\phi$ are fixed, and we are only interested in $R$ restricted to $\vec n\in[n]^k$: this is altogether $n^{O(1)}$ many bits that only depend on $n$ rather than the whole structure, hence they can be supplied as nonuniform advice.

$F(X)$ and $G(X)$: We cannot afford to include the full table of $F$ and $G$ in the description of $\mathcal M$ in the first place, as this would take exponential size. Thus, we will assume that $F$ and $G$ are given to us as oracles that we can query at a given (polynomial-size) argument $X$.


All in all, in this representation, $\mathcal M\models\phi$ can be checked in
$(\Sigma^P_k)^{F,G}/\def\poly{\mathrm{poly}}\poly$ for some $k\ge1$. (Note that here the input proper is just $n$ written in unary; the rest of the structure is supplied by the oracles $F$ and $G$. The polynomial advice is independent of $F$ and $G$.)
To assess what can be computed in $(\Sigma^P_k)^{F,G}/\poly$ by means of $\phi$, let me recall (a relativized version of) the somewhat uncommon counting class $\def\cep{\mathrm{C_=P}}\cep$, which can be defined in several equivalent ways:

$X\in\cep^A$ if there is $R\in\mathrm P^A$ and a polynomial $p(n)$ such that for all $x$,
$$x\in X\iff|\{y:|y|=p(|x|)\land R(x,y)\}|=|\{y:|y|=p(|x|)\land\neg R(x,y)\}|.$$

$X\in\cep^A$ if there are $R,S\in\mathrm P^A$ and a polynomial $p(n)$ such that for all $x$,
$$x\in X\iff|\{y:|y|=p(|x|)\land R(x,y)\}|=|\{y:|y|=p(|x|)\land S(x,y)\}|.$$

$X\in\cep$ if there is $R\in\mathrm P^A$, a polynomial $p(n)$, and $F\in\mathrm{FP}$ such that for all $x$,
$$x\in X\iff|\{y:|y|=p(|x|)\land R(x,y)\}|=F(x).$$


Now, the existence of $\phi$ implies that for all oracles $A$,
$$\tag1\cep^A\subseteq(\Sigma^P_k)^A/\poly.$$
Indeed, fix, say, $R$ and $S$ as in the second definition of $\cep^A$ above. Then we can decide whether a given input $x$ of length $n$ belongs to $X$ by checking whether $\phi$ holds in the structure $\mathcal M=([p(n)],F,G)$, where $F$ and $G$ consist of sets $Y\subseteq[p(n)]$ such that the corresponding binary strings $y$ satisfy $R(x,y)$, resp. $S(x,y)$. Since a query to $F$ or $G$ can be evaluated in polynomial time with oracle $A$ using the input $x$, we can still check this in $(\Sigma^P_k)^A/\poly$. (Note that even though the simulated oracles for $F$ and $G$ depend on the input $x$, the polynomial advice still depends only on $n=|x|$—as it should—because it was independent of $F$ and $G$.)
Now, we just reap the consequences of (1) using a few results from complexity theory. To get from $\cep^A$ to more conventional classes such as PP and #P, (1) implies
$$\def\A{\mathit A}\mathrm{P^{\#P^\A}=P^{PP^\A}\subseteq NP^{\cep^\A}}\subseteq(\Sigma^P_{k+1})^A/\poly:$$
an oracle call to a $\mathrm{\#P}^A$ oracle (i.e., given $x$, count the number of $y$, $|y|=p(|x|)$, satisfying a poly-time predicate $R^A(x,y)$ with oracle $A$) can be simulated by nondeterministically guessing the result, and verifying it with a $\cep^A$ oracle (using the third definition of $\cep$).
Then, (the relativized version of) Toda’s theorem gives
$$\mathrm{PH^\A\subseteq P^{PP^\A}}\subseteq(\Sigma^P_{k+1})^A/\poly,$$
and a relativized version of the Karp–Lipton theorem gives
$$\tag2\mathrm{PH}^A=(\Sigma^P_{k+3})^A.$$
(In fact, with a bit more effort you can show that even $\mathrm{P^{PP}}^A=(\Sigma^P_{k+3})^A$, which then implies by induction that the whole relativized counting hierarchy $\mathrm{CH}^A$ collapses to $(\Sigma^P_{k+3})^A$, but we will not need this.)
All of this is supposed to hold for all oracles $A$. But this is impossible, as it is known that there exist oracles $A$ relative to which the polynomial hierarchy does not collapse, in particular, $(\Sigma^P_{k+3})^A\subsetneq(\Sigma^P_{k+4})^A$.

Concerning the latest edit: the parity of $F$ cannot be defined in this way either, by much the same argument—if it could, we would obtain
$$\tag{1'}\oplus\mathrm P^A\subseteq(\Sigma^P_k)^A/\poly$$
(see $\oplus$P), which again yields (2) by means of another version of Toda’s theorem (and relativized Adleman’s theorem):
$$\mathrm{PH^\A\subseteq BP\cdot\oplus P^\A\subseteq\oplus P^\A/\poly}.$$

Thank you for putting so much time into this. It will take a while for me to look up the relevant stuff to verify, but this is very helpful indeed. And sorry, again, for omitting "monadic".

I hope this isn’t a dumb question: is this still false constructively, seeing as the argument was by contradiction?

@AlecRhea This is a proof of negation. Even a stronger statement of the result in the form “for every sentence $\phi$ there exists a model $\mathcal M$ on which it fails” should be automatically constructive, actually, as it is just a $\Pi_2$ statement, and the whole argument easily formalizes in PA, thus it is provable in HA.

Thank you for the reference and explanation, I am definitely guilty of conflating the two!

@Emil Jeřábek: Do you happen to see off-hand if result remains true if one shifts from finite MSO to WMSO (i.e., infinite set of elements, but second-order quantifiers still range over finite sets)?

I think this is much easier. W(M)SO has the downward Löwenheim–Skolem property. Thus, take a model with uncountable $F$ and countable infinite $G$, which should satisfy $\neg\phi$; by LS, is has a countable submodel that still satisfies $\neg\phi$, but now both $F$ and $G$ are countably infinite, hence the model should satisfy $\phi$, a contradiction.
